# Web scraping with VS Code -- The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code

I've seen this problem come up a few times on here, but I don't really understand the answers/issue, so here goes.

I get this error everything I build:

> The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
>   You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.

This is my code.

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium;


    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
    }
```

This is my csproj file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver" Version="0.24.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="4.0.0-alpha02"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="4.0.0-alpha02"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and the webdriver is in the PATH and is indeed in the bin. If I remove the reference to `IWebDriver`, the project builds fine, so it is definitely something here causing the issue. Any advice?